# Is the search.twitter.com API going to become deprecated in March 2013?

Tags: oauth, twitter, deprecated, twitter-search

I've started to read something about certain Twitter API 1.0 deprecation deadline around march 2013, inviting all their users to migrate onto the 1.1 version of said API. The main difference between the 2 of them (among others) seems to be "the OAUTH thing".

Currently, I've been developing an iOS/Android app, which uses the search.twitter.com/search.json API with no major issues.
The nice thing is that "search.twitter.com" API is an unauthenticated one, and for now, it's more than enough for my needs. I "don't currently want to invest time" onto the OAUTH authentication right now.

On the other hand, and to be honest, I have no idea if the "search.twitter.com" API is the same thing as the 1.0 Twitter API. Is it? Have I been using Twitter API 1.0 without knowing it?

Does anyone know for sure if the search.twitter.com "API" is going to become "also" deprecated on March 2013?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it looks like this API will be deprecated.
You can find more information on Twitter developers forum.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12727

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14587

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14785

So it's time to move 1.1 and OAuth.

Comment: It's now April 2013, has this happened?

Comment: Final retirement date will be May, 7th.
More info:
https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates